# sqlite value to php variable (drupal)

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite, drupal-7

I have little SQL expirience and think this question may be so simple there is almost no support for it online.  How do i pull a single value from a single record in a SQLite database and place it in a php variable?
Here is my *working* code so far...

```
<?php              
$sqlc = db_query("SELECT COUNTY, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM countytable");
$sqlCoutnies = $sqlc->fetchAll();?>
alert('<?php echo count($sqlCoutnies); ?>');              
<?php
```

This returns a popup displaying "100"  which is the correct amount (of counties in iowa). My goal is to create 2 php arrays. One with the key value pair of COUNTY->LATITUDE, and the other with COUNTY->LONGITUDE.  What could i add to my code to create this?

Answer (score 0):

A single record would mean you need a `WHERE` clause in your SQL.

So

```
$sql = 'SELECT county, latitude FROM countytable WHERE id = 1'
```

That returns the county and latitude for the id record number 1.

Comment: I don't want to limit the number of pairs in the arrays.  I want 1 array $county_lat(county1->43.058 , county2-> 42.994 , county3->43.222 ... etc)  And i want a similar one for longitude. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
$county_lat = array();
$county_long = array();
foreach ($sqlCounties as $key => $value){
    $county_lat[$value['COUNTY']] = $value['LATITUDE'];
    $county_long[$value['COUNTY']] = $value['LONGITUDE'];
}
```